# not update ListView scrolling

Tags: android

I do not understand how to perform this operation that you mention.
When I press the button I want to change the amount of food orders
I just want to update the button on the selected topic or, if it does not, activate the entire list

```
public class AdapterFood extends ArrayAdapter<Charola.Producto> {
    ImageView imgFood;

    private String nameService = "AgregarItemCharola";
    private String usuarioId = "UsuarioId";
    private String productoId = "ProductoId";
    private String cantidad = "Cantidad";
    private String especificaciones = "Especificaciones";
    private String urlComplete = Constantes.URLMAIN + nameService + "?";
    private Fragment fragment;
    private List<Charola.Producto> productoList;


    public AdapterFood(Context context, List<Charola.Producto> productoList, Fragment fragment) {
        super(context, 0, productoList);
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.productoList = productoList;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View listViewInflate = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            listViewInflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_menu, viewGroup, false);
        }
        imgFood = (ImageView) listViewInflate.findViewById(R.id.imageFood);
        TextView tituloFood = (TextView) listViewInflate.findViewById(R.id.tittleFood);
        TextView descricionFood = (TextView) listViewInflate.findViewById(R.id.descriptionFood);
        TextView precio = (TextView) listViewInflate.findViewById(R.id.priceFood);
        final Button btnAnadir = (Button) listViewInflate.findViewById(R.id.buttonAnadir);
        final Charola.Producto producto = getItem(position);
        tituloFood.setText(producto.getNombre().toString());
        descricionFood.setText(producto.getDescripcion());
        precio.setText("$" + producto.getPrecio() + ".00");
        if (producto.getCantidad() != 0) {
            btnAnadir.setText("+ Añadir (" + producto.getCantidad() + ")");
            btnAnadir.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btns_dialogs);
        } else {
            btnAnadir.setText("+ Añadir");
            btnAnadir.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_anadir);
        }
        btnAnadir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new consumeServiceAgregarProductoACharola().execute(urlComplete + "#" + producto.getIdProducto());
            }
        });
        Glide.with(getContext()).
                load(producto.getUrlFoto()).placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
                .into(imgFood);
        return listViewInflate;
    }

    //recuperar id usuario
    public int recuperarIdUsario() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MIS_PREFRENCIAS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int valor = sharedPreferences.getInt("id", 1);
        return valor;
    }

    //Asynta


}
```

Comment: please share a bit more details

Comment: Already add more information in the publication. Thank you